# Any realistic advantage of 802.11ac over 802.11n for a regular home connection?

Tags: router, performance, 802.11n, 802.11ac

I am using a 802.11ac Asus - 802.11ac Dual-Band Gigabit Wireless router. Don't have any complains yet but does it really matter to go from a $90 802.11n router to $200 802.11ac router?

In theory, max speed of 802.11ac is 1.7Gbps and 802.11n is 600Mbps ([source](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/160837-what-is-802-11ac-and-how-much-faster-than-802-11n-is-it)). But I am anyway capped with 20Mbps of download speed by comcast (my ISP provider). Assuming range is not a problem because I live in a 2bed house where coverage is good everywhere.

My speedtest currently shows this (comcast):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you don't even saturate half of the standard N bandwidth, if you don't plan on connecting to some other computer and transfer large amount of files (as in create Wireless LAN) then no, there's no reason to upgrade. I've heard nothing new safety-wise about 802.11ac. I see there's a fan in it (good grief) so another source of noise and vibrations.

If you will create WLAN then keep in mind that two devices transmitting between each other will effectively halve the bandwidth, that's where today's 802.11n is inadequate. I just barely play HD movies off NAS (wire to the router and on thru WiFi) and can't use Steam's game streaming in HD. Personally, the sheer bandwidth of 802.11ac makes me drool, but that price tag...

Comment: I have 2 laptops, 2 phones, 1 ipad and 1 Apple TV connected

Answer (score 1):

There may be an advantage, it depends on your environment.

As you increase the distance from your wireless access point, your bandwidth *decreases*. If you have any spots around your house that suffer from low bandwidth, an 802.11ac router may clear this up. For example, I can get a connection on my front porch, but Netflix typically drops its quality out there. It would be nice to upgrade my router and keep full HD.

[MU-MIMO](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001739/ch04.html#multiuser_mu_beamforming) was also introduced in 802.11ac, (Multi-user MIMO [Multiple-input, multiple-output, which also helps with pathfinding and combating interference]), which may make a difference, especially on your phones, when you're using all your devices.